# Find the locus of points on a complex plane that satisfy |z-3| - |z+3| = 4

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

Can you find the locus of points on the complex plane represented by the equation below:

> |z-3| - |z+3| = 4

Comment: Do you know any complex number which is *not* like $a+bi$?

Comment: This equation says that the distance from z to 3 *minus* the distance from z to -3 is constant, equal to 4. This reminds me of the definition of one of the conic sections, and is the theme of these types of questions. How familiar are you with conic sections?

Comment: @ndhanson3 I have studied it in high school, but not sure how to use it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Given two points called the foci (plural of focus), which are $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$ in the picture below, a hyperbola is precisely the locus of points $(x,y)$ such that the difference between $(x,y)$ and the foci is constant.

Since the complex plane can be visualized like an $xy$-plane, this should help. Say $z=x+iy$. Then your equation says that the distance between $(x,y)$ and $(3,0)$ minus the distance between $(x,y)$ and $(-3,0)$ is constant, equal to 4. This is exactly half of the hyperbola you see below with $c=3$. The equation of this hyperbola is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, where $a$ is the real number that's the solution of the equation that you should try to find, and $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

[image: hyperbola picture]

Reference and more info: [https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakercollegealgebra/chapter/equations-of-hyperbolas/#:~:text=Reviewing%20the%20standard%20forms%20given,%3D%20a%202%20%2B%20b%202%20](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakercollegealgebra/chapter/equations-of-hyperbolas/#:%7E:text=Reviewing%20the%20standard%20forms%20given,%3D%20a%202%20%2B%20b%202%20).

Comment: Note: in order to get both halves of the hyperbola, you would also need the solutions to the equation $|z+3|-|z-3|=4$.